# counting number of digits in a number which contains zeros at the left side

Tags: c

How can we count the number of digits in a number which contains zeros at the left side? For example for the integer input `0012`, it should display `4` and for integer input `0000` it again should display `4`. Actually, first I want to check the number of digits in the number and then want to check whether it is even or odd.

More examples to clear the understanding for number of digits:

```
integer input:012 output:3
integer input:00001 output:5
integer input:1010 output:4
```

Comment: decide for one language! C and Java would have **nothing** in common regarding how to do *this*.

Comment: And additionaly, clarify your exact requirements. Do you want to *verify* it actually *is* a number? Your inputs are strings, and in both languages, there's a simple way to get the length of a *string*.

Comment: @amoldambale: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey check mark below its score.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple way to compute the number of digits at the start of a string, including initial zeroes:

```
#include <string.h>

size_t count_digits(const char *s) {
    return strspn(s, "0123456789");
}
```

`strspn()`, a lesser known but standard function, counts the number of characters at the start of its first string argument that are present in the second string argument. Its counterpart `strcspn()` counts the characters that are not present in the second string argument, it can be used to remove the trailing newline from the buffer filled by `fgets()`: `buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';`.

Comment: First correct answer, and verification could be added by simply comparing the result to `strlen(s)`.

Comment: Or more directly: `size_t count = strspn(s, "0123456789"); if (s[count] == '\0') { /* no extra characters */ }` but one should also test that `count > 0`.

Comment: The OP tagged this thread as both Java and C; This answer is therefore only half correct, since it will not work for Java.

Comment: @FredK "*language will be preferable.*" ... and then, it should be 2 questions if it's really needed in both languages.

Comment: @FredK-- OP stated that C would be preferable, but in any case, partial answers are perfectly acceptable on Stack Overflow. So, feel free to contribute your own Java answer....

Answer (score 0):

[chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593267/chqrlie)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44739384/2371524) is arguably the simplest possible solution in C if you don't want to go with a simple `strlen()`. The following would be a bit more efficient:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

size_t numDigits(const char *str)
{
    size_t n = 0;

    // increment counter while the character is a digit:
    while (isdigit(str[n])) ++n;

    return n;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [number]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    size_t digits = numDigits(argv[1]);
    if (argv[1][digits]) // not end of string after the digits found
    {
        puts("not a number");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%zu digits\n", digits);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The C Standard mandates that the digits `'0'` to `'9'` be consecutive, so no problem with that, but `isdigit(str[n])` has undefined behavior if `char` is signed and `str[]` contains negative characters...  Use `isdigit((unsigned char)str[n])` or `str[n] >= '0' && str[n] <= '9'` instead.  But why return `(size_t)-1;`, a huge positive value, if there are trailing characters?

Comment: @chqrlie for being able to distinct this from the result of an empty string. -- good catch about the `unsigned char`, I'll edit this. Stupid age-old functions taking `int` ....

Comment: Trailing characters may not be a problem: the OP says nothing about that and `atoi()` and `strtol()` ignore them.

Comment: @chqrlie OP doesn't say much at all, I was just bored and *assumed* a requirement to verify the string is a number ;) -- `strtol()` makes it possible to check using `*endptr`. Would have been a possible interface for my function as well.

Comment: That would be redundant: you already return the number of initial digits: it is trivial to verify if the following character is the end of the string.

Comment: Sorry to be picky, but the empty string is not really a number. Also the cast `(size_t)` is redundant.

Comment: @chqrlie well THAT depends ;) Is nothing == 0? I guess `0 digits` is kind of a precise description. Whatever, this toying around has gone far enough ;)

Comment: @chqrlie I already caught and removed this, it was left from a first test with `ssize_t` (stupid idea)

Answer (score 0):

I'm new here but most languages have a trim left & right function to remove spaces and a Len function to return a string length so something like:

```
nbrdigits = len(rtrim(ltrim(inputstring)))
```

Assuming that only digits were input.